# Macerator toilet

Tags: bathroom

The switch for my macerator toilet is in a cupboard which I can’t access to turn it off while I put cleaner on it. Is there an alternative for cleaning it while switched on?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the manufacturer's instructions to not clean the toilet with the power on, if they say to do that.

You can get a local electrician to move the switch. Also, if the toilet is plug-in, you might be able to unplug it. Don't run extension cords to enable unplugging it, though. That would be dangerous in a bathroom and would likely also violate the manufacturer's instructions.